# Настройка stack для работы через прокси-сервер

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

На работе используется корпоративный прокси-сервер. 
Можно ли как-то заставить stack работать через него? 
Операционная система Windows-10

**UPDATE**

Вот что получается при запуске stack:

```
PS X:\Pet> stack update
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/
Downloading root
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/) ...
SomeRemoteError (HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = [("Accept-Encoding",""),("Cache-Control","no-transform"),("User-Agent","The Haskell Stack")]
  path                 = "/hackage.fpcomplete.com/root.json"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (InternalException (HostCannotConnect "s3.amazonaws.com" [Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 712>: failed (Connection timed out (WSAETIMEDOUT))])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrowd говорил все верно. Проблема оказалась в том ,что у нас все же https-proxy.

Установить понадобилось, соответственно, переменную среды https_proxy. Как выяснилось опытным путем, stack умеет работать и с ней.

```
set https_proxy=http://user:pass@ip:port
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить переменную среды `http_proxy`, например

```
set http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:5678/
```

Подключение к прокси по HTTPS пока не работает: https://github.com/snoyberg/http-client/issues/175

Comment: пробовал. Либо я не понимаю проблему, либо что-то не получается. Сейчас добавлю в вопрос то ,что выдает stack.